# Should there be a tag for "school / study / university" projects?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

I was thinking last night about another tag we could add to the pm site for better categorization of "school", "study", or "university" projects and was unable to find something along those lines.

Perhaps even [study] would be enough to capture & categorize questions related to these types of questions.

Is this something that has been discussed / thought of?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there is no such tag and basing on experience from other sites I'd say that for the time being we don't need it at PMSE.

This is the old discussion whether we should have meta tags, like homework or, in other words, study. As on most sites they decide not to introduce such tags I'd do the same here.

The reason for having such tag would be if someone wanted to filter out homework/study questions from professional ones. If you ask me, we don't have such problem now, as we barely have more than one fresh question daily on the site, so I guess most of frequent visitors skim through all of them anyways.

Maybe we're going to come back to this discussion later, when there are more questions at PMSE, but then we may be discussing whether we want such question at all. Either way for the time being I'd say that it works OK the way it works now.

Comment: I agree that at this time such a tag would be considered a meta-tag and not supported. Since the site is a Q&A for project management, in theory, all questions could hypothetically be marked as "study" or "homework".

Answer (score 1):

I personally use tags to find information which will be of interest to me.

Searching for school, study or university is too broad and I believe it will have no benefit to the community. We are all here to learn and share knowledge, so I think that these tags are obsolete.

Regarding the "homework" tag, I do think that certain homework questions must be frequently moderated as they don't belong in this community. People who ask these kind of questions, would rarely tag their question as a homework as they normally want to keep it quite and have somebody solve the problem for them. These kind of questions are normally easy to spot, so they get closed/moderated promptly.